# How to mock a C-function using OCMock

Tags: objective-c, c, unit-testing, ocmock

How do I mock a custom c-lib function using ocmock?  Couldn't find anything on google, and any method stubbing functions from OCMock doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be to encapsulate that functions inside an static class and mock it. In this way you can test the functions itself and mock his usage (using the static class).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mock C functions with OCMock. You will need to use another framework.

Comment: do you have another framework that you suggest to mock C functions?

Comment: I haven't used any, so I hesitate to make a recommendation.

Comment: You can use fishhook(https://github.com/facebook/fishhook) from Facebook